# Is it possible to modify add extra headers in AppGyver?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I am going to my external server, I would like to pass some header variables like X-CLIENT-NAME . Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

For a cordova solution, you'll need to either compile your own cordova lib or use a plugin such as [cordova-HTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP), specifically `setHeader`, from the README:

```
cordovaHTTP.setHeader("Header", "Value", function() {
console.log('success!');
}, function() {
console.log('error :(');
});
```

With Angular, you can also use the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` object in order to set your headers for all requests, just POST, or just PUT.  See the Setting HTTP Header section here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score -1):

With Supersonic, you can set extra headers directly for INCOMING responses:

```
network:
  extraResponseHeaders:
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, X-Requested-With"
```

This allows you to add extra response headers to responses coming in, so e.g. even if your server doesn't give CORS headers, you can force them. There's no similar native-level `extraRequestHeaders` setting ATM.

Comment: I think the point was to add the headers to OUTGOING requests.